# Is there an issue with my CPU or CPU socket? Beep codes with CPU 4pin connector plugged in

Tags: boot, memory, cpu, motherboard

I'm really hoping this isn't the problem, but it seems to be.

Whenever I attempted to boot my machine, I got a long single beep that would repeat. (The motherboard I am using is a Gigabyte H110M-A)

I tried re-seating the GPU and memory, but the same code occurred.

I tried one stick of RAM, and the same beep happened.

I took out all the memory and the beeps still happened when I turned on the PC.

The only time the beep code did not sound was when I unplugged the 4 pin connector for the CPU.

Is it likely that the CPU is broken, or maybe the socket? This is a new build, so I highly doubt that the CPU is the cause. If it is the socket, is there any fix, or must I just order a new motherboard?

Comment: So you removed the power from your CPU? If it's the socket then you likely have bent pins, those can't be fixed, in most cases

Answer (score 0):

#### What does BIOS beep sound mean?

Check which BIOS your motherboard has and look below for the exact error.

> **AWARD BIOS**
>
> - 1 short beep ：System normal
> - 2 short beep ：CMOS Error
> - 1 long beep and 1 short beep：Memory error
> - 1 long beep and 2 short beep：Graphic card error
> - 1 long beep and 3 short beep ：AGP error
> - 1 long beep and 9 short beep ：Memory Error
> - Continuous long beep ：Memory not correctly installed
> - Continuous short beep ：Power supply unit failed 2.
>
> **AMI BIOS**
>
> - 1 short beep ：Memory Error
> - 2 short beep： Memory parity check error.
> - 3 short beep ：basic memory 64K address check error
> - 4 short beep ：Real Time Clock malfunction .
> - 5 short beep ：CPU error
> - 6 short beep：Keyboard error
> - 7 short beep ：CPU interruption error
> - 8 short beep：Graphic card error
> - 9 short beep ：Memory error
> - 10 short beep ：CMOS error
> - 11 short beep ：CPU cache memory malfunction

Source [What does BIOS beep sound mean?](http://www.gigabyte.com/Support/Faq/816)

Comment: I referred to this, but I really can't see how the memory is affecting it. I've tried using one stick of memory, and removing them all. The same beeps occur no matter how the RAM is organized.

Comment: Actually thinking about it, the speaker wouldn't emit sounds if the socket was damaged right? Could it be that the motherboard just isn't detecting my RAM?

Comment: @g____g No idea :/

Comment: @g____g it's extremely likely the speaker would work